# Having nodes at the baseline and in mid-air with tikz-qtree

Tags: linguistics, tikz-qtree

I want to draw the following tree:
[image: Tree from Lohnstein (2007)]

What I have so far is the following, but this code puts all nodes onto the baseline. I would like to keep T° and Foc° up. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every roof node/.append style={inner sep=0.1pt,text height=2ex,text depth=0.3ex}}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={level distance=2\baselineskip}}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}} % enables \\ in nodes
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=30\baselineskip}}
\Tree[.TopP
       [.SpecT left\\dislocated\\elements ]
       [.T$'$ T$^0$ 
         [.FocP
           [.SpFoc {[+wh]-phrases} ]
           [.Foc$'$ Foc$^0$ 
             [.TopP 
               [.SpecT {[$-$wh]-phrases} 
               [.T$'$ Top$^0$ 
                 [.AgrP SpecAgr
                   [.Agr$'$ 
                     [.MoodP
                       [.{} ]
                       [.Mood$'$ 
                         [.TenseP
                           [.{} ]
                           [.Tense$'$ 
                             [.vP theta-layer ]
                             Tense$^0$ ] ] 
                         [.Mood$^0$ {verbal mood\\factive vs.\\epistemic} ] ] ]
                      Agr$^0$ ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep the roof node structure even for the empty ones. Fiddling with your code gives the following; notice the extra brackets here and there

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{every roof node/.append style={inner sep=0.1pt,text height=2ex,text depth=0.3ex}}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1+/.style={level distance=2\baselineskip},
                    every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north},
                    frontier/.style={distance from root=30\baselineskip}]
\Tree[.TopP
       [.SpecT left\\dislocated\\elements ] 
       [.T$'$ [.T$^0$ ] 
         [.FocP
           [.SpFoc {[+wh]-phrases} ]
           [.Foc$'$ [.Foc$^0$ ] 
             [.TopP 
               [.SpecT {[$-$wh]-phrases} ] 
               [.T$'$ [.Top$^0$ ] 
                 [.\node(a){AgrP}; [.\node(b){SpecAgr}; ]
                   [.Agr$'$ 
                     [.MoodP
                       [.{} ]
                       [.Mood$'$ 
                         [.TenseP
                           [.{} ]
                           [.Tense$'$ 
                             [.vP theta-layer ]
                             [.Tense$^0$ ] ] ] 
                         [.Mood$^0$ {verbal mood\\factive vs.\\epistemic} ] ] ]
                      [.Agr$^0$ ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\draw[ultra thick,dashed] ($(a.north west)!-3cm!([yshift=-1cm]b.north west)$)  
                        --($(a.north west)!1.5!(b.north west)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. My installation asks me to include `
\usetikzlibrary{calc}`. But then it works.

Comment: @StefanMüller Ah yes I forgot that. Sorry